# html5 acceleration not triggered by audio on phones

Tags: javascript, jquery, accelerometer, html5-audio

I want to trigger an audio file when i shake my phone. i can get audio to play with button press. I can also get it to play on shake but only after an initial button press. I don't want to have to press a button first for the audio to play on shake...

javascript:

```
        var audio = new Audio('electornicnoise.mp3');

        $(document).ready(function() {

            function onShake() {
                audio.play();
            }

            $.shake({
                callback: function() {
                    onShake();
                }
            });

        });
```

html:

```
<button onclick="audio.play();">audio</button>
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this in the end by adjusting the volume. So the user still has to click a button, but the audio that the button click plays is at volume 0, whereas when the audio is played through shake, the volume is at 0.5. This is the code...

javascript:

```
        var audio = new Audio('electornicnoise.mp3');

        audio.volume = 0;

        function gotIt(){
            audio.play();
            $('#copyContainer').hide();
            $( "img.bg" ).effect( "shake", {times:2}, 300 );
        }8    

        $(document).ready(function() {

            function onShake() {
                audio.play();
                audio.volume = 0.5;
                $( "img.bg" ).effect( "shake", {times:20}, 3000 );
            }


            $.shake({
                debug: "#debugdiv",             // debug div id
                supported: "#notsupporteddiv",  // not supported message div
                violence: 3.0,                  // single shake sensitivity
                hf: 0.2,                        // high-pass filter constant
                shakethreshold: 10,              // number of single shakes required to fire a shake event
                debounce: 1000,                 // delay between shake events (in ms)
                callback: function() {
                    onShake();
                }
            });

        });
```

html:

```
        <div id="copyContainer">
            <p>Shake the present to hear what's inside</p>
            <button id="gotIt" onclick="gotIt();">Ok got it!</button>

            <div id="notsupporteddiv">
                <p>Your device is not supported.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```